# Libgdx resize window on android to fill screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to fill the resize function that comes with Libgdx to fit all of the android screens.

The best solution I have seen so far is this tutorial: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25685.0 but when I run it on my Galaxy S3 the buttons are really tiny and just overall the whole game is tiny where on the desktop version it is big and the way I want it to be. My resize code right now is:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    float aspectRatio = (float)width/(float)height;
    float scale = 2f;
    Vector2 crop = new Vector2(0f, 0f); 
    if(aspectRatio > ASPECT_RATIO)
    {
        scale = (float)height/(float)VIRTUAL_HEIGHT;
        crop.x = (width - VIRTUAL_WIDTH*scale)/2f;
    }
    else if(aspectRatio < ASPECT_RATIO)
    {
        scale = (float)width/(float)VIRTUAL_WIDTH;
        crop.y = (height - VIRTUAL_HEIGHT*scale)/2f;
    }
    else
    {
        scale = (float)width/(float)VIRTUAL_WIDTH;
    }

    float w = (float)VIRTUAL_WIDTH*scale;
    float h = (float)VIRTUAL_HEIGHT*scale;
    viewport = new Rectangle(crop.x, crop.y, w, h);
}
```

My render code is:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    // update camera
    camera.update();

    // set viewport
    Gdx.gl.glViewport((int) viewport.x, (int) viewport.y,
                      (int) viewport.width, (int) viewport.height);

    // clear previous frame
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    ScreenManager.updateScreen();

    sb.begin();
    ScreenManager.renderScreen(sb);
    sb.end();
}
```

And my variables are:

```
private static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 600;
private static final int VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 800;
private static final float ASPECT_RATIO = (float)VIRTUAL_WIDTH/(float)VIRTUAL_HEIGHT;

public static BitmapFont FONT;

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Rectangle viewport;
private SpriteBatch sb;
```

Like I said, when I run the desktop version it works fine but when I run it on my Galaxy S3 (Screen Dim: 1,280 x 720), the game is zoomed out a lot, and it crops out the tops and sides of the game which is not what I want at all.

Comment: Can you log the viewport values that get defined and what width/height  are being used on your S3?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is 1,280 x 720

Comment: Are you drawing screen elements relative to viewport.x and viewport.y, or are they relative to 0,0?  I think logging some of the actual numbers being used will help shed light on what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean exactly. Am I starting my x and y coordinates of where I draw textures at the viewpoint coordinates? I wouldn't be doing that no. I would of thought it would have automatically did that.

Comment: @Jon, I just implemented that and experienced what you did. The post below that starts with "Thanks for the Scaling tip." worked brilliantly as a replacement for the `resize` method with coordinates relative to (0, 0).